# Short story where spectators at a sports match shine a mirror at the referee and burn him

Tags: short-stories, identification-request

I read a short story long ago. I can't remember the details but I would like to reread it. What's it's title?

The story is a science fiction story concerning some sports match. A referee makes a bad call and then the hats of the spectators reflect sunlight burning him. I also remember the author is pretty famous but I can't remember who.

I read it online in a collection of sci-fi stories 4-5 years ago. It's probably 20th century. It might have been Clarke or Asimov.

Comment: You will have to provide more detail than that. When did you read this? Where? Was it an anthology or a magazine? What language? You can consult [this page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to help jog your memory.

Comment: I read it online in a collection of sci-fi stories 4-5 years ago. It's probably 20-th century. It might have been Clarke or Asimov.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add details you come up with.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Nah, it's a classic, perfectly recognizable from the description.

Comment: @Gilles I'm changing the title because no official in association football has been called an "umpire" for decades now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be [“A Slight Case of Sunstroke”](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62811) by [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke). Like most of Clarke's story, it's a hard SF story (perfectly physically plausible). It's one of two stories by Clarke where someone is killed by a death ray, the other being [“Let There Be Light”](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62810).

In “A Slight Case of the Sunstroke”, the setting is a football match between the national teams of two fictional Latin American countries, and the spectators have been (unknowing to them) instructed to orient reflective material in such a way as to kill a political opponent of the order giver. In “Let There Be Light”,

> a driver is blinded and loses control of his car.

<sub>[This story has also been sought on SF&F.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59555/searching-for-football-related-short-story)</sub>